# Sass: Multiply sum of px to rem function

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to multiply the sum of a calculation performed in a function but I get the following error:

`"Undefined operation: "pxToRem(4) times 3"`

Whilst I could use rems directly it's a lot easier for me to work in pixels. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and if there's a way to solve it? I'm not trying to multiply a string and I'm not multiplying a unit by a unit so I don't understand where the problem is.

```
// Declare px to rem function
$browser-context: 16;
@function pxToRem($pixels, $context: $browser-context) {
  @return ($pixels / $context) * 1rem;
}

// Call the px to rem function
$column-unit: pxToRem(4);

// Multiply sum of px to rem function
$column-span: $column-unit * 3;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to check your compiler. I ran a test in Codepen and it appears to be working correctly. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PePyOB?editors=1111

Comment: @disinfor you solved it thanks. All my functions were in a separate partial which I imported into another partial and the references to them must have been missing. I should have just imported everything into the main.scss as usual. If you change your comment into an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer otherwise I'll post an answer myself stating you solved it for me.

Comment: Glad you got is solved! I only helped get you going in the right direction, you can create the answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a convenient to think in rem, use body {font-size:62.5%;}. The rem will be as quick easily associated with px. E.g. 1.4rem=14px. It's an easier and more elegant method I feel. 
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm asking, I'm not looking for a convenient way to think in rem. If you double check that article, you'll see that font-size: 62.5% should be set on the <html> tag and not the <body> tag as rems are relevant to the value in <html> not <body>. As stated in the article this method has limitations.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments @disinfor solved the problem. The code I posted was working but on my development server I was importing the function from another file that wasn't being referenced correctly. The lesson I learnt is to import all your files into one main.scss as normal and don't try to cross import them.

Comment: I've marked down the other answer as it didn't relate to my question and currently has a higher rating than the correct answer so is misleading. Thanks for trying to help though.